# Rails Dates Time and Fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fixtures

I had the following fixture:

```
link_1:
  user: tom
  image: boy1
  created_at: <%= 5.day.ago %>
```

I tried the following request:

```
Links.where("Date(created_at) = ?", 5.day.ago.to_date)
```

Answer:

```
[]
```

grrrr....typing...typing...scratching...
I finally tried:

```
link_1:
  user: tom
  image: boy1
  created_at: <%= 5.day.ago.to_date %>
```

and

```
Links.where("Date(created_at) = ?", 5.day.ago.to_date)
```

finally answers

```
[#<Link id: 298486374, user_id: 1038054164, image_id: 482586125, created_at: "2010-11-28 00:00:00", updated_at: "2010-12-03 21:32:19">]
```

What I was expecting, but why did I need to put to_date? It is not clear to me, because when I create an object without specifying the creation date, I can select them with the following where clause without issue:

```
Links.where("Date(created_at) = ?", Date.today)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Let me be clearer, my question is: Why is my query working when I put .to_date in the fixture and not when I don't put it.

Comment: I would consider switching to predictable values instead of dynamic. Some examples: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1505f8b69209c02ff60f124220590bde20bb7c09/activerecord/test/fixtures/topics.yml

Answer (score 26):

In fixtures you should have:

```
created_at: <%= 5.day.ago.to_s(:db) %>
```

Your query will be a:

```
Links.where("created_at = ?", ...
```

Let ActiveRecord taking care of the details about moving data from and to the database. We are using an ORM for a reason.

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s).

Comment: to_s(:db) is the way to go here, I've run into this myself.

Comment: 5.day.ago == 5.day.ago.to_date => false is clear to me, but it is not the issue here, my points was that it IS working when I put .to_date

Comment: In your fixture you are casting 5.day.ago (of type `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`) to `Date`. Whatever is saved in the database, is later casted in `Date` within your query with `Date(created_at) =...`. `Date` doesn't care of hour or the timezone of your Rails app. Fire up `rails console` and compare the results you have entering `5.day.ago`, `5.day.ago.to_date`, `5.day.ago.to_s(:db)` to have something empirical to look at. You will see different _values_.

Comment: Once again, it is clear to me that Date and Time or DateTime have different values. But here "created_at" is a dateTime, that I am casting to Date, thus, ignoring the time attributes. So I should be able to compare with a date

Comment: Using .to_date in your fixture you are saving a representation of a Date obj in the database. Later the query gets that representation of a Date object and successfully compare it with 5.day.ago.to_date that is again a Date object.

Comment: This isn't true - the comparison is happening in the database, so what kind of objects Rails represents them with is irrelevant. Besides, using `DATE()` in a `WHERE` clause doesn't change the type of object Rails returns, because a `WHERE` clause doesn't change the values returned by the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Using `.to_date` in fixtures is relevant to how the data is saved in the database, so how it is later compared by the database. I agree with you, using DATE() in a WHERE clause doesn't change the type of object Rails returns.

Comment: to_s(:db) is most important bit of info here!

Answer (score 1):

I would speculate that it's because of the time difference between when the fixture was created and when the query was called.

5 days ago + 0.00025 ms > 5 days ago

I'm not sure what the precision is for datetimes, but it's the only possibility I can think of. When you converted it to a date, your removed the extraneous time information and rendered the two equal.

Comment: This is not a timezone issue since the last example Links.where("Date(created_at) = ?", Date.today) is working fine

Comment: I'm not saying it's a timezone issue. There's a small delay between when the datetime was inserted as a fixture (We'll say 12/05/2010 12:00:00.0000) vs when it was being compared (12/05/2010 12:00:00.0005). That's the time difference I was speaking of.

Answer (score 1):

`created_at` is a DateTime field, and `5.days.ago` effectively returns a DateTime object. This object will have the same time set as at the moment it is called, eg. Sat, 23 Aug 2014 10:30:**37**, and this is what gets put into the database.

In your failing case, when you call `5.days.ago` again later (even in the same execution) the new time will likely differ, eg. Sat, 23 Aug 2014 10:30:**38**. Therefore you can see that they are not equal, and you will get no matches.

When you append `.to_date`, you get a Date object, which has no time component. When this gets persisted to the database, or used in your query, it will always be regarded as having a time of 00:00:00 (midnight). Therefore the date and time will match, (as long as you don't try running the fixtures and query exactly over midnight)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your two cases is that when you call `to_date`, you lose the time value, and so the end result is a `created_at` timestamp set to midnight of that day. You also avoid the time zone translation from `TimeWithZone`. Frankly, we don't have enough information to conjecture what is happening beyond this. To see exactly what is going on, your best bet is to look at the queries in your `log/test.log` - if you don't see queries, you can turn them on by setting `log_level` to `:debug` in `config/environments/test.rb`. Feel free to copy and paste the SQL queries here.

@Ibz also raises a good point: using `.to_s(:db)` is a good idea, because the fixture file ERB is evaluated to a string and then read in as YAML, which can cause some issues with casting of values to strings. Using `.to_s(:db)` will fix this problem, but to avoid this in the future (and gain a bunch of additional features), I'd recommend using [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) instead of fixtures.

These kinds of issues are common when dealing with testing dates - particularly if you are trying to query by equality of two dates or timestamps. To tackle these issues, I recommend either picking arbitrary fixed dates/times in the past instead of doing `5.days.ago`, or if you do need to use dynamic dates/times, use the [Timecop gem](https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop) to control/freeze time within your tests.

Comment: My question was more "why is it working" than "why is it not working"