# Rails doesn't generate created_at for fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timestamp, fixture

I have a model Question with "question_id", "elapsed_time", "allowed_time" and "status" as its fields and a controller named Reporting that receive JSON containing questions and save it. ("question_id" is not related to any of my models)

So far there is no problem. Until I try to run some tests. I've an error when Rails is trying to load my Question's fixture :
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: questions.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "questions`"

Here's my fixture :

```
one:
  id: 1
  question_id: MyString
  app: MyString
  guid: 1
  status: 1
  elapsed_time: 1
  allowed_time: 1
```

and my model :

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :app
      t.integer :guid
      t.string :question_id
      t.integer :elapsed_time
      t.integer :allowed_time
      t.datetime :happened_at
      t.integer :status

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My model's name was in plural form. Change it to singular and rails will generate timestamp.

See how rails generate timestamp : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L560

Answer (score 2):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350202/978525 you can add something like the following to your fixture objects:

```
objectA:
  foo: something
  created_at: <%= 5.day.ago.to_s(:db) %>
  updated_at: <%= 5.day.ago.to_s(:db) %>
```